# How to do conditional polling in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I want to do conditional Polling in Primefaces (Version:6.0.0).

**Here is the polling code:**

```
<p:poll  interval="20" update="liveChart,chrtTC_Cnt_Status,chrtStatus" />
```

For Example, I am field call **Status**. If status value is '`In-Progress`' then only polling should start. Or else it should not do polling.

Here is my field code, if this value changed to 'In-Progress' then polling should start or else not

```
<p:outputLabel value="Status:" />
<p:outputLabel id="lblCurrentStatus" value="#{backingBean.status}" />
```

**Here is my Xhtml code**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" width="400">

                    <p:outputLabel for="lblStudentName" value="Select Other StudentName: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="lblStudentName" style="width:250px" 
                        value="#{backingBean.selectedStudent}"
                        panelStyle="width:180px" effect="fade" filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""
                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.studentItemList}" />
                        <p:ajax
                            listener="#{backingBean.OnChangeOtherStudentDropDown}"
                            update=":idForm:tabStatus:p1,:idForm:tabStatus:p4,growl"
                            process="@form" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>


                <p:tabView id="tabStatus">
            <p:tab title="Status" id="idStatusTab">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="10" id="p1">
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
                        onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" />

                    <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false"
                        closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                    </p:dialog>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" id="p2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Failed:" />
                        <p:outputLabel id="lblCurrentFailed"
                            value="#{backingBean.intCurrentFailedStudent}" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Processed:" />
                        <p:outputLabel id="lblCurrentProcess"
                            value="#{backingBean.intCurrentPassedStudent}" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Status:" />
                        <p:outputLabel id="lblCurrentStatus"
                            value="#{backingBean.status}" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="p3">

                        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{backingBean.pieModel1}"
                            rendered="#{not empty backingBean.pieModel1}"
                            id="chrtStatus" style="width:300px;height:200px">
                        </p:chart>
                        <br />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>


                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="10" id="p4">

                <p:poll  interval="20" update="liveChart,chrtTC_Cnt_Status,chrtStatus" />
                    <p:chart type="line"
                        model="#{backingBean.lineCurrentLineChart}" 
                        rendered="#{not empty backingBean.lineCurrentLineChart}"
                        id="liveChart" style="height:500px;width:500px" />


                    <p:chart type="bar"
                        model="#{backingBean.barStatusCountStudent}"
                        rendered="#{not empty backingBean.barStatusCountStudent}"
                        id="chrtTC_Cnt_Status" style="width:500px;height:500px">
                         <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{backingBean.itemSelect}"  />
                    </p:chart>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Wrap your `p:poll` tag within `h:panelGroup` or `h:panelGrid` and set `rendered="#{backingBean.status eq 'In-Progress'}"` on panel.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, It is working but now I have observed that polling start if Status is 'In-Progress' but I want to stop when Status changed to 'Failed'. However, Polling doesn't stop. It Stops when I Press F5. Any Idea?

Comment: From which component is your status changing? You can update panel of poll on change of that component, that will reset your polling.

Comment: Or other way around is to set `autoStart="false"` and `widgetVar="statusPoll"` on `p:poll` and then you can manually start / stop by invoking `PF('statusPoll').start();` and `PF('statusPoll').stop();` on changing the value of status field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Wrap your `p:poll` within `h:panelGroup` or `h:panelGrid`, set `rendered="#{backingBean.status eq 'In-Progress'}"` on panel and update panel on changing of status, that will reset your polling.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to manually start and stop the polling then you need to set `autoStart="false"` and add `widgetVar="statusPoll"` attributes on `p:poll` and by invoking `PF('statusPoll').start();` and `PF('statusPoll').stop();` on changing the value of status field.

Comment: When I have done mention code, Polling start like first 1 time, second polling 2 times, 3rd polling 3 times. and goes on. Below is the code.                         
        `<p:tab title="Status" id="idStatusTab">
     <h:panelGrid  id="p1">
   </h:panelGrid>
  <h:panelGrid  id="p4">
    <h:panelGrid  id="ID_polling"
     rendered="#{backingBean.status eq 'InProgress'}">
     <p:poll interval="20" rendered="#{backingBean.status eq 'InProgress'}"
      update="tabStatus"
      async="false" />
    </h:panelGrid>
   </h:panelGrid>
  </p:tab>`

Comment: I mean to ask, on what is your `status` field getting updated?

Comment: `Status` field gets update initially, In-Progress, then Fail or Pass

Answer (score 0):

It is working,

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" id="ID_polling" rendered="#{BackingBean.status eq 'In-Progress'}">    
          <p:poll  interval="20" update="liveChart,chrtTC_Cnt_Status,chrtStatus" />    
</h:panelGrid>
```

When I write this Panel, Panel will display only when status = 'In-Progress' or else it will not display.

Thank you again,

Comment: Why didn't you just accept the @Parkash Kumar answer?